# Linear Programming Problem About Inventory and Cost Minimizing

Tags: linear-programming

http://www.endustri.anadolu.edu.tr/zkamisli/ENM%20203/duyuru/ENM203%20Assignment%202.pdf

In that link, you can find my question. I'm having trouble about defining decision variables.

The objective function must minimize the cost of 6-months period.

Last one, should I solve this problem by dividing it to 6 parts(months) or by looking at the big picture?